# The power series $\sqrt{1-z}$ about zero converges absolutely for all $|z| \leq 1$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

I am following a proof for this claim (from Reed & Simon's book on functional analysis) which lets
$$\sqrt{1-z} = 1 + c_1 z + c_2 z^2 + \ldots$$
be the power series of $\sqrt{1-z}$ about the origin. They state:

> Since $\sqrt{1-z}$ is analytic for $|z| < 1$, the series converges absolutely there. The derivatives of $\sqrt{1-z}$ at the origin are all negative, so the $c_i$ are negative if $i \geq 1$. Thus $$\sum_{n=0}^N|c_n| = 2 - \sum_{n=0}^N c_n \tag{1}$$ $$= 2 - \lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-} \sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n$$ $$\leq 2 - \lim_{x \rightarrow 1^-} \sqrt{1-x} \tag{2}$$ $$ = 2.$$

I am having trouble seeing how they obtained (1) and (2)? How does (1) follow from the $c_i$ all being negative, where did 2 come from? For (2), how do we know that $\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n \geq \sqrt{1-x}$?

Comment: For $0<x<1$ we get $\sum_{n=0}^N c_n x^n \geq  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_n x^n=\sqrt{1-x}$

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you, I forgot that the $c_i$ are all negative. Is the condition $0 < x < 1$ to ensure convergence?

Comment: $x>0$ is needed for the inequality. $x<1$ is already there since you want left hand limit at $1$.

Comment: @geetha290krm Thank you.